# bulk/batch convert mp4 and m4v files to webm via command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webm

is it possible to convert mp4 and m4v to webm via command line?

I'd like to just in a bulk swoop convert my mp4 and m4v files to web so i can play them in firefox without any issues.

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but this will reduce video quality (even if you use the same or higher bitrate as the original).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with `ffmpeg` and `bash` this is not only possible, but very easy.

Here is the command for variable bit-rate conversion for .mp4 -> .webm:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

You can then use the command in a bash script to batch covert your files. Here is an example of how you could do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.mp4 ; do
    OUTNAME=`basename "$FILE" .mp4`.webm
    ffmpeg -i $FILE -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis $OUTNAME
done
```

Keep in mind that depending on your computer, this may take a very long time.

And of course, this can be done for the m4v files as well. I won't guarantee everything will work since I don't have ffmpeg installed on this machine to test it, so you may need to modify the script and/or the conversion settings to suit your needs.

Documentation for the webm encoder can be found here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide

Comment: The `basename` is superfluous when you can use [bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) instead: `for FILE in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "${FILE%.mp4}.webm"; done`